# How to refresh android view height when sibling position changed?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I have an Android Layout like this :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_layout"
        android:orientation="vertical">
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rv_weighing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/cv_price_holder"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!-- another view elements here -->
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Basically I want the first element fill the remaining space between parent and the second element. It works fine until I change the Y position of the  second element at runtime. I tried to call `.invalidate()` and `.requestLayout()` on both parent and the first element but it seems like doesn't work as expected.

I also tried to change the parent layout using `<RelativeLayout>` and set `android:layout_above="@+id/cv_price_holder"` on the first element but didn't work as well.

EDIT : Here is the method that invoked to toggle the layout :

```
public void togglePriceHolder(){
        float newY = mPriceHolderToggleState ? -mPriceHolderToggleLimitY : mPriceHolderToggleLimitY;
        int newIcon = mPriceHolderToggleState ? R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_down_white_36dp : R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_up_white_36dp;
        mBtnTogglePriceHolder.setImageResource(newIcon);
        mCvPriceHolder.animate().translationYBy(newY).setListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                // refresh the layout
                rvWeighing.forceLayout();
                mMainLayout.requestLayout();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {}

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {}
        });    
        mPriceHolderToggleState = !mPriceHolderToggleState;
}
```

The question is how can I refresh the layout so the first element can adjust its height when Y position of the second element change ?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try calling [forceLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#forceLayout%28%29) on the views whose dimensions might change and then calling [requestLayout()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29).

When `requestLayout()` is called on a view, all the parents of that view are redrawn, but the siblings are not, calling `forceLayout()` on a particular view, marks that view for the next layout pass(along with the default traversal).

In your particular case, try calling `forceLayout()` on the siblings you want to redraw, and then call `requestLayout()` from one of the views.

Comment: Hi Sarthak, thanks for your help but I still cant make it work. I edited the question to add the method I use to toggling the layout. Am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: @qatz one thing you can try is to call requestLayout on mCvPriceHolder rather than mMainLayout, and sorry for the late reply...